# Errors using ps2ascii on some files

Tags: operating-system, ghostscript

What does `FC_WEIGHT` refer to? Please advise: Although a text file was produced it is large and consists largely of numbers which makes it hard to proofread. I need relatively good confidence the output matches the input. If there is a fix please point me to it and bring joy to my dull drab existence.

entered the command 
`ps2ascii /Users/dwstclair/Desktop/untitled3/stmt_20181130.pdf a.txt`

The result was: 
`DEBUG: FC_WEIGHT didn't match`

On the off chance a default font was missing on my system 
I added DroidSansFallback.ttf (no joy)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I wouldn't use ps2ascii. Its long been deprecated and doesn't even ship in more recent versions of Ghostscript.

Instead consider using the txtwrite device. It works with a wider range of input (in particular it can use ToUnicode CMaps in PDF files, which ps2ascii cannot) and is capable of producing output in other than ASCII, which is quite useful. Even if you aren't working with non-Latin languages, the ability to preserve ligatures (eg fi, ffi, ffl etc) is convenient.

The actual answer to your question is 'don't worry about it'.

FC_WEIGHT refers to the weight of a font (light, bold, regular, ExtraBold etc). This message can **only** arise when you are using FontConfig, and Ghostscript is enumerating the available fonts from font config, trying to find a match for a missing font in the input. This means that a candidate font did not match the target font's weight.

Since you aren't going to use the font, it doesn't affect you.

Comment: What would you suggest to replace for converting pdf > txt?

Comment: As I said in my answer, consider using the Ghostscript txtwrite device. The original ps2ascii only really deals with PostScript input, and is limited in the Encodings it can handle. The txtwrite device is usable with any of the languages the Ghostsceritp family supports, can use ToUnicode CMaps and has a series of fallbacks to try and figure out the real text. It also has a few different output options so you can recover the data in different ways. There are other tools which will do a similar job with PDF as well, such as MuPDF, and I'm sure there are more if you only want to deal with PDF.

Comment: Thanks I don't know how I missed it.